# Server port 9081 is in use, starting Websphere Application Server in RAD

Tags: rad, launch, websphere-portal

very quick question regarding an issue I never seen before. I've being using RAD 6 for java development, with Websphere portal server 5.0 installed. When I trying to start the server, I get the following error in a popup:

[image]

Which none of what's described is the true in my case...and still the case even though I rebooted the PC, as well as checking for any redundant javaw.exe processes.

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

I asked a colleague, they suggested that you have a server set up which is defined to run as a service. Since the service will start automatically with Windows, rebooting won't help.

Check your services.msc and see if there's a service for WebSphere, then try stopping it and starting your server from within RAD.

Comment: Thanks @jjokin for you time on my question. Unfortunately I'm not able to find any processes or programs related to Websphere in services.msc. It's a development pc I'm using, no other process should be running apart from me..

Comment: Hi @jjokin, are there any other possibilities for the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing, if it's possible. Just go to running programs and check for any java.exe and stop/delete all of them. And try restarting your server. And check if it makes any sense.

Hope it helps.

//HP

Comment: Thanks @HP24, there's no Java.exe running when I closed RAD.

Answer (score 0):

Start command prompt (if you're on Windows Vista and up, ensure you start it in admin mode).

Type:

`netstat -a -b`

This will show you all ports being listened. Look for `9081`, and then you'll be able to see the process that is capturing that port.

Which process was it?

Comment: Thanks Isaac, I'll have a look

Comment: When I start Websphere Portal server in RAD, I get the error. Doing `netstat -a -b` among the big list, I saw **TCP xxxx549233:2884 localhost:9081 TIME_WAIT 0 <br\> TCP xxxx549233:2889 localhost:9081 TIME_WAIT 0** Otherwise these entries don't appear

Comment: Oh. You must be using Windows XP. Also looked at the screenshot you attached: looks like Windows XP to me. On Windows XP, use `-o` instead of `-b`. You will get the process ID of the process that owns the port. Then use Microsoft's Process Explorer (free Microsoft utility) to see which process it is.

Comment: Here's some reference for `netstat` (Windows XP): http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/netstat.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Thanks a lot Isaac, I'll have a look

Comment: Hi Isaac, did what suggested, same result, the pid was 0. The OS for my dev machine is windows server 2003. Checked Process Explorer, pid 0 is the system idle process

Comment: The system idle process is capturing port 9081? that means that there's an OS-internal process of some sort, holding that port open. Or malware of some sort. Sorry, I am out of ideas on that one. Anybody?

Answer (score 0):

An easiest way to do so is kill the jawa/javaw process from the taskmanager. 
And then start the server.